# why npm install react-router-dom not installing?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, react-router

*I have tried it many times still getting the same error*, it continues to run showing the following warnings*

node

v15.5.0

npm

6.14.10

````
npm ERR! path D:\PORTFOLIO\myportfolio\node_modules\.bin\json5.cmd
npm ERR! Refusing to delete D:\PORTFOLIO\myportfolio\node_modules\.bin\json5.cmd: ..\@babel\core\node_modules\json5\lib\cli.js symlink target is not controlled by npm D:\PORTFOLIO\myportfolio\node_modules\json5

npm ERR! File exists: D:\PORTFOLIO\myportfolio\node_modules\.bin\json5.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shradha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-27T06_20_35_403Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: I do not see any errors just warnings.

Comment: @yudhiesh ya, but these warnings are not ending like it continues to show

Comment: It is just a warning because of `fsevents` on windows.

Comment: @Rohit I am getting the above errors 'edited'

Comment: Go to your `package.json` and check that `react-router-dom` is actually downloaded successfully.

Comment: @yudhiesh No, ```"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },```

Comment: @yudhiesh yes, its installed now, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with the current stable node version 14.15.3